# how to create a synonym in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, ddl, synonyms

some one tell me the basic syntax for creating synonym for the table employees

```
create synonym for emp for app.employees
```

while creating it shows error 
 **ORA-00995: missing or invalid synonym identifier**

Comment: The manual will tell you the basic syntax: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7001.htm#SQLRF01401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have [checked the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7001.htm#SQLRF01401). There is an extra `for` which is syntactically incorrect:

```
create synonym emp for app.employees;
```

Also try a `desc emp`. The `ORA-00995` error can also be produced if there is an existing object with the name of the synonym (emp in your case).